# Bind data to axis ticks d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would bind data to my axis ticks (generated by ordinal scale) to use it later on mouseover event.

I don't want to display it, just bind it:

```
  //data what I would like to bind on each tick (eg. "<0,1" tick binded to 10
//"<0,2" tick binded to 28
//"<0,3" tick binded to 4
//...
  var data = [10,28,4,6,10,65,87,54, 9, 1,45];
//what is display on tick
  this.xLabelsValues = ["<0,1", "<0,2", "<0,3", "<0,4", "<0,5", 
                        "<0,6", "<0,7", "<0,8", "<0,9", "<1", "=1"];

  this.x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, this.width], .1);

    this.x.domain(chart.xLabelsValues);

    this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(this.xAxis);

//my event
 this.svg.selectAll(".tick").on("mouseover", this.mouseover);

  this.mouseover = function(d, e){
   //I want my binded data here!
};
```

Is that possible or I've to trick something?

Answer (score 0):

The ticks are already bound to the tick values.

Something like this trick to set some extra data:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")[0].forEach(function(tick){
          //set the data all ticks
          d3.select(tick)[0][0].myData = {foo:"bar"} 


        });
```

get data from ticks

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")[0].forEach(function(tick){
          //set the data


          console.log(d3.select(tick)[0][0].myData)
        });
```

Comment: yep I knew it's bind to tickValues, actually it's what you get from first event param. Ok I've done something like this already, so there aren't fancy way (I mean d3 built in) to do that? Thanks btw, you confirming what I was doing so. I will still test your solution tomorrow which is a bit different!

Comment: @JulienLeray you could at least vote the answer up if not mark it as correct