# Bind data to axis labels

Tags: d3.js, bind, axis, label

I am using d3 v4. I want to bind data, d.name, to the axis labels. But use different values, d.num, in the data for the domain.

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, newdata) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data = newdata;
    var name = [];

    // data.forEach(function(d) {
    //   // console.log(d.name);
    //   if (name.length < data.length - 1) {
    //     // console.log("name.length = " + name.length);
    //     name.push(d.name);
    //   }
    // });

    // xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0);

    xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0).tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      console.log("name[" + i + "] = " + name[i]);
      console.log("data[" + i + "].name: " + data[i].num);
      // return name[i];
      return d.name;
    }).ticks(name.length).tickSize(10);

............

});
```

The data,

```
[{
    "name": "A",
    "num": "1",
    "distance": "1900"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "num": "2",
    "distance": "1500"
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "num": "3",
    "distance": "2500"
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "num": "4",
    "distance": "2300"
  },
  {
    "name": "E",
    "num": "5",
    "distance": "2000"
  }
]
```

The problem is that data is not bound to the xAxis variable. How could i do this?

As can be seen in the commented section of code I tried passing the d.name values to an array called name. But this causes issues later on, so that is why I am trying to bind the actual data d.name to the labels.

There is a similar post [Bind data to axis ticks d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313854/bind-data-to-axis-ticks-d3-js?rq=1) but this was 2010 and so not for v4. Also i am not sure how to apply that in my situation.

Thanks,

Comment: In your last edit you added a linear scale, which was **not** in the original question and makes my answer incorrect and worthless. I rolled it back. Feel free to ask *another* question with the relevant details or, if you really want to edit this one, for whatever reason, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a datum bound to each tick in the axis: it is the elements in the domain of the scale passed to the axis.

In your specific situation, the best idea may be using `filter` with the zero index (or `find`, if the browser supports it) to get the object in the data array based on the datum of the tick (again, corresponding to the scale's domain).

However, answering your question's title (*"how to bind data to the axis"*), you can this by directly manipulating the first argument (inside `tickFormat`, for instance, or even an `each` function). However, this will mess with the current datum.

A safer approach is using a [local variable](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables), like...

```
var local = d3.local();
```

... which you can use to get the object in the data array by index. After that, the local variable will be bound to the DOM element.

Have a look at this demo, the axis is made using a scale that has `num` for the domain, but it will change after 1 second for the `name` property, using the local variable bound to them:

```js
var data = [{
    num: 1,
    name: "foo"
  },
  {
    num: 2,
    name: "bar"
  },
  {
    num: 3,
    name: "baz"
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var local = d3.local();

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([50, 250])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.num
  }))

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    local.set(this, data[i].name);
    return d;
  })

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
  .call(axis);

d3.timeout(function() {
  axis.tickFormat(function() {
    return local.get(this)
  });
  gX.call(axis)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. d3.local() is new to me. The issue I now get is that it can't see the name property in the data. Full code is here https://github.com/shanegibney/stackoverflowQuestion Thanks

Comment: Instead of using GitHub, why don't you create a running code using Plunker, Blockbuilder or something like that? It's easier to debug and modify.

Comment: @ShaneG The problem here is that you're using a linear scale, in which the number of ticks **do not correspond** to the data elements. That's why you're getting undefined.

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is use brush and zoom on a linear scale because it is smooth. Then I wanted to simply replace the ticks marked 1,2 and 3 etc with the labels A, B and C. This would have the effect of a scaleband but be smooth when panning using the brush. But it seems to be more complicated than that. This is the brush effect I don't want https://shanegibney.github.io/Interactive-Data-Visualisation-3/ and this is the brush effect I want, but with scaleband https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Bar-chart-Scaleband-with-Brush/ thanks

Comment: Well, so we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Please post a new question explaining the desired outcome, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Sorry the effect I want is https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-Bar-Chart-Pan-And-Zoom/ not what I linked to in the comment